# CNN: accuracy and loss are increasing and decreasing

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'am beginner  in deep learning, I created 3DCNN using Pytorch.

input image: 120 * 120 * 120

the problem that the accuracy and loss decrease and increase in the same interval [45,56].

Can you help me please ?

```
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNNModel, self).__init__() 
        
        self.conv_layer1 = self._conv_layer_set(3, 32) 
                                                       
        self.conv_layer2 = self._conv_layer_set(32, 64) 
        self.conv_layer3 = self._conv_layer_set(64, 128)
        self.conv_layer4 = self._conv_layer_set(128, 256)
        self.conv_layer5 = self._conv_layer_set(256, 512)

      
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(512, 128) 
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, num_classes)  
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.batch=nn.BatchNorm1d(128)
        self.drop=nn.Dropout(p=0.5, inplace = True)   
        
    def _conv_layer_set(self, in_c, out_c):
        conv_layer = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv3d(in_c, out_c, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), padding=0),
        nn.LeakyReLU(),
        nn.MaxPool3d((2, 2, 2)),
        )
        return conv_layer
    

    def forward(self, x):
        # Set 1
        out = self.conv_layer1(x)
        out = self.conv_layer2(out)
        out = self.conv_layer3(out)
        out = self.conv_layer4(out)
        out = self.conv_layer5(out)
        out = out.view(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        out = self.batch(out)
        out = self.drop(out)
        out = self.fc2(out)
        #out = F.softmax(out, dim=1)
        return out
```

Result :

teration: 1/10  Loss: 0.8040086030960083  Accuracy: 47.023809523809526 %

Iteration: 2/10  Loss: 0.8323351740837097  Accuracy: 45.23809523809524 %

Iteration: 3/10  Loss: 0.8008261322975159  Accuracy: 50.595238095238095 %

Iteration: 4/10  Loss: 0.7527135610580444  Accuracy: 55.95238095238095 %

Iteration: 5/10  Loss: 0.7785584330558777  Accuracy: 51.19047619047619 %

Iteration: 6/10  Loss: 0.7463465929031372  Accuracy: 56.25 %

Iteration: 7/10  Loss: 0.8021382093429565  Accuracy: 52.083333333333336 %

Iteration: 8/10  Loss: 0.7705538868904114  Accuracy: 50.595238095238095 %

Comment: when i remove the dropout layer the accuracy and loss does not change for all epochs

Comment: May be you have to decrease your learning rate?! Also move activation after maxpool and batchnorm to conv_layer.

Comment: thank you for your reply @DimitriK.Sifoua I tried to decrease the LR but the problem was not solved

Comment: What is your loss function?

Comment: `error = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`